# Subject in English

Tags: grammar, american-english

I'm Japanese and I am studying English, in particular, reading English books. I have some questions about the subject.

We also use pronouns in Japanese. Then, a subject usually does not change from line to line. For example, if we say  the following sentence in Japanese,
"Lon wrote a letter. He sent it to Jacob. He was excited."
then the last "he" means Lon; whereas, if we say the above in English, the last "he" can mean both "Lon" and "Tom", as I studied.

In English, isn't it hesitated to change a pronoun from line to line?

Best

Comment: We try to avoid this unless the context makes the interpretation clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in thinking that this could cause confusion, as the second "he" could mean either of the two previously mentioned people. To avoid this, I would explicitly state the subject of the second one, like this:

> "Lon wrote a letter. He sent it to Jacob. Jacob was excited."

Another way to disambiguate, as @Janus Bahs Jacquet mentioned, is to use relative clauses. In this case, the subject of the clause would be relative to the preceding subject:

> "Lon wrote a letter and sent it to Jacob, who was excited."

or...

> "Lon wrote a letter. He sent it to Jacob, who was excited."

Comment: Or, perhaps more commonly, resolve the issue by using various grammatical/syntactic tools available to disambiguate, such as (in this case) relative clauses: “Lon wrote a letter and sent it to Jacob, who was excited [at receiving the letter, presumably]”.